# Load only body content using tiles struts2

Tags: ajax, struts2, tiles

Im developing web application that has technologies of Tiles struts2. The problem is when I navgate through pages each time whole page will load.So the menu and header footer also load each time. I thought tiles gonna solve this issue..but still its load whole page for each navigation.
My Tiles :

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="mainTemplate" template="/pages/template/mainTemplate.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Title" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/pages/base/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/pages/base/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/base/defaultHome.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/pages/base/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="atOrganisationTemplate" extends="mainTemplate">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Organisation" />

        <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/admin/atorganisation/organisationSearch.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="list" value="/pages/admin/atorganisation/organisationList.jsp" />

    </definition>
    <definition name="atOrganisationAddTemplate" extends="mainTemplate">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Organisation" />

        <put-attribute name="body"
            value="/pages/admin/atorganisation/organisationAdd.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="list"
            value="/pages/admin/atorganisation/organisationList.jsp" />

    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Main Template :

```
<body>
<div id="dialogd" title="Confirmation Required">
Do you really want to delete selected row
</div>
    <div class="container-fluid master-depot-wrp">

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3 master-depot-left">
            <div class="inner-logo"><img src="img/logo.png"/></div>
                <div class="left-menu-wrp">

                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />

                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/LEFT span-->

            <div class="span9 master-depot-right">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="depot-header">
                        <span class="header-text"><tiles:insertAttribute
                                name="title" /></span>

                        <div class="header-menu">
                            <em class="login-user"></em><span>User
                                    Name : <s:property value="User.auUsername" />
                            </span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|
                             <a href="<s:url action="logoutsecurity"/>"> <em
                                class="log-out-link"></em><span>Log Out</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- header end -->

                    <div class="toolbar-wrp">
                    <ul class="toolbar-menu">
                    <li><sj:submit formIds="post" value="" title="SAVE" cssClass="bt-save ttp"/></li>
                    <li><sj:submit formIds="add" value="" title="ADD" cssClass="bt-add ttp"/></li>
                    <li><sj:submit formIds="delete" value="" title="DELETE" cssClass="bt-delete ttp"/></li>
                    <li><sj:submit formIds="search" value="" title="SEARCH" cssClass="bt-search ttp"/></li>
                    <li><sj:submit formIds="edit" value="" title="EDIT" cssClass="bt-edit ttp"/></li>


                    </ul>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- row-fluid end -->
            </div>
            <!-- span 9 end -->
<div class="span9 body-wrp">


    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="list" />

</div>



        </div>
        <!-- row -->
    </div>
    <!-- master -->


<footer class="depot-footer">
```

Can you guide me to achieve what I need?
I saw some articles about this loading problem using ajax and those are not clear(If you want whole code I can provide.)
Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood, but if you want, you can create another template without any menu/footer/header and just use for your jsp. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: If you need to load only part of page then use ajax, tiles won't do ajax for you.

Comment: Can you give give tiles ajax struts2 integration example to achieve this... @AleksandrM